# PostFix+Dovecot: Case Sensitive Email Address

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

So I'm having a problem with my email server configuration. I setup my server using [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu-14-04#comments). It works great my only problem now is that the email address is case sensitive. I understand why that is because of how Linux handles case sensitivity but this is my personal server and there is only going to be a few users. So user@mysite.com will go but User@mysite.com will bounce.

Message:

> : host mysite.com[private/dovecot-lmtp[ said: 550 5.1.1  User doesn't exist: User@mysite.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)

I've searched for hours and haven't found the solution. I made the below changes but they didn't help.

```
::dovecot.conf
auth_username_format = %Lu
::/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%Lu
```

Also all my packages are up-to-date.

Comment: Please include your postfix configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Unix usernames are case sensitive, alias database lookups in Postfix are not. You could e.g. use [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) & [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) instead of [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) for your domain to make the user part of the address case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks Esa. That worked I added a new alias 'User1: user1' and now it's case insensitive.

Comment: Should it be possible to use virtual_alias_maps and address rewriting rules to do this generically, so that it works for any capitalisation and any username?  I can't figure out how though.